# Asp.net Core behind a Nginx Ingress Controller on AWS EKS got "502 Bad Gateway"

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, aws-nlb

I follow the guide from [aws](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/) and successfully have a EKS cluster with a NLB in front of the Nginx Ingress Controller. The routes working fine, I can access the /banana and /apple, look okay to me

Then, I try to add another ASP.net app and update the ingress

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: moba-web-portal
  labels:
    app: moba-web-portal
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: moba-web-portal
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: moba-web-portal
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: moba-web-portal
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3001
          protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: moba-web-portal
spec:
  selector:
    app: moba-web-portal
  ports:
   -  protocol: TCP
      port: 3001
      targetPort: 3001
```

```html
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "128k"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffers-number: "4"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - api.kmsmoba.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: api.kmsmoba.com
    http:
      paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/moba"
          backend:
            service:
              name: moba-web-portal
              port: 
                number: 3001
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/apple"
          backend:
            service:
              name: apple-service
              port: 
                number: 5678
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/nodejs"
          backend:
            service:
              name: ecsdemo-nodejs
              port: 
                number: 3000
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/banana"
          backend:
            service:
              name: banana-service
              port: 
                number: 5678
```

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out why I just got "502 Bad Gateway" when I try to access the path /moba-web-portal

I also tried to switch the service name "moba-web-portal" to use another docker image which is built with nodejs then it works okay, so I am doubt on the asp.net application, but that might not be the problem since I use docker image from Microsoft. So, I guess I missed some configuration for the Ingress, could you advice a clue?

Edited: I also tried to test my docker image inside the EC2 worker node, my docker image looks good with the docker run command

Edited to provide more screen captured
[image]

Comment: Whats status for  `/moba`   access ?

Comment: /moba got "502 Bad Gateway"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asp.net core sample listen to port 80 and not 3001, update your deployment:

```
...
containers:
- image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  name: moba-web-portal
  ports:
  - containerPort: 80
...
```

And the service spec:

```
...
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: moba-web-portal
spec:
  selector:
    app: moba-web-portal
  ports:
  -  protocol: TCP
     port: 3001
     targetPort: 80
...
```

Check the log of the pod:

`{"EventId":14,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","State":{"Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","address":"http://[::]:80","{OriginalFormat}":"Now listening on: {address}"}}`

Try: `http://api.kmsmoba.com:3001/moba` takes you to the homepage "Welcome to .NET"

Comment: yes, deployment and pod are ready, edited the question to provide more information

Comment: my worker node is a Linux based

Comment: try out the updated answer

Comment: yes, thanks, by default asp.net expose 80 and 443 
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443